# Entry point for STM32 firmware

Tags: firmware, arm, hopper, entry-point

I'm trying to disassemble a firmware for a DIY project, open hardware but closed firmware.
My question is how to initialize the disassembler properly (Hopper Disassembler).

The values I try to figure out are the ones shown here:

[image: Hopper Disassembler]

From what I know, the processor is a STM32F100C8, ARM Cortex-M3, 64Kbytes Flash, 8Kbytes RAM. The BOOT0 pin is tied low, so I know it's booting from main flash memory:

> Boot from main Flash memory: the main Flash memory is aliased in the
>   boot memory   space (0x0000 0000), but still accessible from its
>   original memory space (0x800 0000).   In other words, the Flash memory
>   contents can be accessed starting from address   0x0000 0000 or 0x800
>   0000.

The startup sequence is as follows:

> The CPU fetches the top-of-stack value from address 0x0000 0000,
>   then   starts code execution from the boot memory starting from 0x0000
>   0004

I converted the .hex file to a .bin file using `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` and found:

```
0x0000 0000  |  10050020 (Stack pointer) 
0x0000 0004  |  05A90008 (ResetHandler)
```

What I don't understand are the memory addresses.

The stack pointer is too large to be a relative offset (only 8K RAM) and too small to point into SRAM (starting at 0x2000 0000).

The reset handler is also too large to be a relative offset (only 64k flash) and too small to point to main flash memory (starting at 0x800 0000).

How do I figure out the proper base address and entry point?

PS: The schematics and firmware for the DIY project can be found [here](http://fandy.ucoz.org/publ/metalloiskatel_quot_kvazar_quot_quot_quasar_quot/metalloiskatel_quot_quasar_arm_quot/2-1-0-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values are in little-endian I believe so the stack pointer is at 0x20000510 and the reset vector is 0x0800a905.

Comment: doh! how could I miss that!